# Python 3 urllib + PySocks - open url with SOCKS4 proxy fails

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

Trying to open URL with a SOCK4 proxy in Python with urllib and PySocks fails with

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Socket error: 0x5b: Request rejected or failed>
```

Has anybody got an idea what could be the problem and why it fails? Or does anybody have another method for opening a URL in Python with a SOCKS4 proxy (tried urllib and PySocks documentation examples)?

I check and the proxy is up and should work (tried with others - always fails the same while using SOCKS4 as scheme). Using a HTTP as proxy works just fine - `proxy = proxies[1]`.

```
import socks
import socket
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler
import contextlib
from urllib import request

TIMEOUT = 50

if __name__ == '__main__':

    headr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X  vAppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

    proxies = [("SOCKS4","88.198.224.84", 4145), ("HTTP","159.69.91.65", 3128)]
    proxy = proxies[0]
    teipe = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4
    if proxy[0] == "SOCKS4":
        teipe = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4
    elif proxy[0] == "HTTP":
        teipe = socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
    #socks.setdefaultproxy(teipe, proxy[1], proxy[2])
    #socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    shandler = SocksiPyHandler(teipe, proxy[1], proxy[2])

    baseurl = "https://google.com/"
    opener = request.build_opener(shandler)
    request.install_opener(opener)

    req = request.Request(baseurl, data=None, headers=headr)
    with contextlib.closing(request.urlopen(req, timeout=TIMEOUT)) as googl:
        print("Opened " + baseurl + " with " + str(request.getproxies()))
```

Debugging the error does not help me - the error.reason.socket_err is:

```
SOCKS4Error: 0x5b: Request rejected or failed
```